# BB 10: Difference between cascade, core and web-works app

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-cascades

I want to know basic difference between **Cascades**, **Core** and **WebWorks** apps. Can WebWorks-based apps interact with device apps? Or they can simply run on web end? Please somebody clear it for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert, but in short

**WebWorks** - it is web based, but you can use some core APIs. [Take a look here](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/beta/). I'm not sure, but if I remember correctly you can even write your own libraries in core, to access more

**Cascades** - it's front-end (QML part) and back-end (QT). It has a lot more access to core then WebWorks. Very simple to make good looking apps, and good functionality

**Core** - I think it's mostly used for games, and app ports, but has big access to system functions.

Comment: Also Cascades makes it easy to write Built for BlackBerry apps, and they run at 60fps.